# For loop variants comparison

Tags: c++

There is a `for` loop like this:

```cpp
uint32_t WORD_COUNT = // ... a constant number
using Word = uint64_t;
Word mWords[WORD_COUNT];

uint32_t n = WORD_COUNT;
for (Word* w = mWords; n--; ++w) *w = Word(0); // <= Original loop
```

Can the original loop be written like this?

```cpp
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) mWords[i] = Word(0); // => Is this the same loop?
```

Is there any benefit in writing the loop in the original shape?

Comment: Looks the same to me. I see no benefit in the original either. It's just more obscure. You could also use a for range loop `for (auto& w : mWords) w = Word(0);`, or `std::fill_n(mWords, n, Word(0));`

Comment: @john Right, thanks =)

Comment: Note that compilers are smart enough to turn the second loop into the first one if it's faster. They didn't used to be that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the loop is used to initialize that array, you could just write

```
uint32_t WORD_COUNT = // ... a constant number
using Word = uint64_t;
Word mWords[WORD_COUNT] {};
//                      ^^ 
// See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
```

Otherwise, as [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) mentioned

> You could also use a for range loop `for (auto& w : mWords) w = Word(0);`, or `std::fill_n(mWords, n, Word(0));`

I can't see any benefit in writing the loop like in the first posted snippet.